# Accessing photos from a specific album from photolibrary

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

While using uiimagepicker, is there any way of specifying which user created album the images should be picked from?Ill explain.Suppose there are two albums created by the user in the ipad.Let them be named 'friends' and 'students'.Is there any way of specifying which one of these albums the photos should be accessed from ?or How can i know the name of the album the picked image belongs to?

can it be done via alsset methods?What i want to do is access photos from a particular synched album using their names.Is it even possible.I mean does iphone use its own naming conventions or are the original image names retained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ALAssetsLibrary and make your own custom picker. You can find a custom image picker using ALAssetsLibrary at https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController

When the user selects an image from the custom picker, you are returned with the ALAsset object from which you can get the required image, album it belongs to etc. You can save that and modify the custom picker to navigate to a selected album.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present a media browser to the user (so that he/she can pick an image), I think you can only choose to present the entire photo library or the Camera Roll album (or Saved Photos album, if the device hasn't a camera).

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010408-SW1

**EDIT**

I've found 
[here, on github](http://github.com/jeena/JPImagePickerController) an open source UIImagePickerController clone by Jeena. Maybe, it should be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but pls take a look at [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722)

Answer (score -1):

Give the path for specific album and get the images.

Comment: how do you get that path? and where do you give it to?

Answer (score -3):

hello
in the folder: /Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications you can find your images that are saved.
when you save the path you maybe can substract the name of the folder.
grtz

Comment: but i want to find the folder name while the app is running