# How to directly open a directory of images using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using this code to open Image Gallery :

```
...
self.albumPicker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [self.albumPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    self.albumPicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,(NSString *)kUTTypeImage,nil];
    [self.albumPicker setDelegate:self];
    [self.albumPicker setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
...
```

Is there a possibility to directly open a directory that is in the gallery?

Comment: R U want to open direct a specific album?

Comment: you should have to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855534/accessing-photos-from-a-specific-album-from-photolibrary

Comment: Because UIImagePicker not allow this kind of customization.

Comment: You can also read this accepted answer with bounty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457868/uiimagepickercontroller-open-in-camera-roll

Comment: you may have to create a custom imagepicker for this kind of requirement